# How to remain dollar sign in gradle?

Tags: shell, gradle, groovy, sed

## **Update:2017/06/21**

I try to make this question more clear. I want to modify a file(named meta67.config) which including a **String**.

**$BUILD_PATH="/abc/Bach/buildroot-2015.05"**

That String should be replaced with

**$BUILD_PATH="/workspace/kuanlin/abc/Bach/buildroot-2015.05"**

So, I write the command into build.gradle like this.

```
task build(type:Exec) {
    def cmd = """
    set -e
    sleep 2
    cd /workspace/kuanlin
    echo "\$BUILD_PATH="/workspace/kuanlin/abc/Bach/buildroot-2015.05";" > config/mt6755.config
    """

    executable "bash"
    args "-l", "-c", dockerCmd(cmd)
}
```

After I execute gradle build, cat mt6755.config will display like this, the String of **$BUILD_PATH** will always disappear.

```
=/workspace/modem/mtkeda/Bach/arm7/20150805/buildroot-2015.05;
```

Comment: what does `dockerCmd` do?

Comment: you did not escaped all backslashes. for example this one: `\"/workspace` and this one: `2015.05\"`

Comment: It doesn't work either.

Comment: Please provide a clear command line that works in bash.

Comment: I got the answer, because I assigned the command to a task's object(cmd), the docker will read this command from dockerCmd(cmd) while executing, so I need to put more backslash in front of dollar sign like this: echo "\\\\\$BUILD_PATH="/workspace.......